# i'm getting error for production release ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

hi i'm getting this `error`  for production release,

i'm running this `command`

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

getting this `error`

> Error: Type ContactLiteHirePage in
>   D:/litehire_app_new/src/pages/contact-lite-hire/contact-lite-hire.ts
>   is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
>   D:/litehire_app_new/src/app/app.module te a new NgModule that exports
>   and includes ContactLiteHirePage in
>   D:/litehire_app_new/src/pages/contact-lite-hire/contact-lite-hire.ts
>   then import that NgModule in AppModule in D:/litehire_app_new
>       at Error (native)
>       at syntaxError (D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1550:34)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14655:31)
>       at D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14543:27
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14534:54)
>       at addNgModule (D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23050:58)
>       at D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23061:14
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at _createNgModules (D:\litehire_app_new\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23060:26)

**what i have done is**

removed this from every `ts` file

```
import {.....} from 'ionic-angular';  // removed IonicPage

@IonicPage()  // removed
```

**below is error screen shot**

[image]

Comment: do you have an `IonicPageModule` that imports ContactLiteHirePage  ?

Comment: The error is clear you add `contact-lite-hire.ts` to two module. you need to remove one of them.

Comment: can you post your app.module.ts here?

Comment: @goutham-ggs delete the `contact-lite-hire.module.ts` file in `D:/litehire_app_new/src/pages/contact-lite-hire/`